# Why can't I add 1 to the value of a Hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using Sequel ORM

```
@latestorder = Step.where(:tutorial_id =>data['tutorial_id']).order(Sequel.desc(:order)).limit(1) #data['tutorial_id'] is 1
@neworder = @latestorder[:order] +1; #<-- this line causes errors!

NoMethodError at /makenew/stepundefined method `+' for #<Step:0x2f85138>
```

Using `.to_i` does not work and I cannot use `DB[]` for this query.

**Output of @latestorder and @latestorder[:order]**

```
<?r @latestorder.inspect ?>
```

> #

```
<?r @latestorder.each do |late| ?>
#{late.inspect}
<?r end ?>
```

> #13, :user_id=>1, :tutorial_id=>1, :order=>9, :title=>"Choose a group", :instruction=>"From the groups page, choose one of the groups to go on. \r\n\r\nFor testing purposes if you have the password for flyasakite, choose the All About Compesh group", :url=>"http://compesh.com/groups", :datenumber=>"2012-11-10", :datetimenumber=>"2012-11-10 13:18"}>

```
<?r @latestorder.each do |late| ?>
#{late.order.inspect}
<?r end ?>
```

> 9

I need to be able to add 1 to the @latestorder that has a LIMIT of 1, without going inside an `.each` loop

Comment: Can you print the output of `@latestorder[:order]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@latestorder` is a Sequel::Dataset, if you want it to be a Hash, you need to change `limit(1)` to `first`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@latestorder` is an array, get the first element, and try to use that:

```
@neworder = @latestorder[0][:order] +1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or because Sequel has different array/hash id's depending on the id of the row.

`@neworder = @latestorder.first.order +1`